# Upgrade Aurora MySQL version 1 to Version 2/3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I received an email regarding Amazon aurora mysql 1 (with MySQL 5.6 compatibility) will reach end of life.
I am trying to follow the steps in the AWS document (upgrade using console) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.MajorVersionUpgrade.html#AuroraMySQL.Upgrading.Procedure

Steps as per document:

1. Login to Amazon RDS console.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Databases.
3. Choose the DB cluster that you want to modify.
4. Choose Modify.
5. For Version, choose an Aurora MySQL 2.x version.
6. Choose Continue.

Issue I face:
When I select Modify after selecting the DB cluster i need to modify, I DONT find the Version.

Can anyone help me with this. Where can i find the version option.

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,
SP

Comment: what is your engine version ? Do you see a maintenance message in the console for your instance ? If not then it might be phased out region by region. Please check that kindly.

Comment: Engine version is 5.6.10a (Engine: Aurora MySQL). Apologize for delayed reply

Comment: Having the same issue.